# Storing binary data as nvarchar/varchar data in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to store `binary` data as `varchar`/`nvarchar` in SQL servers tables?

Example I am trying to store binary data  `0x6806000004000000` as `nvarchar` data type but while trying to save to the tables values are getting blanked out. I want them to be stored as strings

Code used

```
declare @tempBinayToVarchar table (FinalValue NVARCHAR(60))
Insert into @tempBinayToVarchar
select Value from basetable
```

Values in the table are values like:

```
0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004
```

Comment: Why not use the varbinary type?

Comment: Even if I cast binary to varbinary and try saving to SQLServer , it is getting stored as   blank

Comment: The binary value `0x00` as a `varchar` is a null character, so could cause display issues. That doesn't mean that the data isn't being stored, it just can't be displayed. How the application displays the value may be completely different. Notice that [SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU6Aj.png) and [ADS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Moqm2.png) give different results for the same query here, for example.

Comment: Please post your code and results so we can see exactly what it is you're doing.

Comment: Not blanked out for me if you use `varbinary` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3eabf2d117752981e20077c36d87ef44

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to just store the `0x000...` as a string *without converting it to what the binary value actually represents*, you can do that using `CONVERT(0x000..., 1)` though, for the specific value in your question, you need more than 60 characters.

```
DECLARE @tempBinayToNvarchar table (FinalValue nvarchar(120));

INSERT @tempBinayToNvarchar(FinalValue)
  SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(120), 
    0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004, 
  1);
  
SELECT FinalValue FROM @tempBinayToNvarchar;
```

Output:

| FinalValue |
| --- |
| 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f50fffa663c1c106508e6d09da822b77)

Comment: I like that we have both bases covered here. *How* to store a string representation of a binary value in a table, and what happens when you don't properly convert the value.

Comment: Note that implicitly converting the `varchar` value `'0x00'` back to a `varbinary` won't yield `0x00` either, @PraveenN . You would need to again explicitly convert with a style code.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:** Store your binary data in a `varbinary` and if you "must" store it in a `(n)varchar` data type, don't expect readable information.

---

The value *isn't* being blanked out. As I mentioned in the comments, the value `0x00` as a `varchar` (`0x0000` for an `nvarchar`) is a `null` character; applications *can't* display this character and many actually parse it as the *end* of the string.

That, however, doesn't mean the value is gone, it just can't be displayed. You can see this with the following SQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.SomeTable (BinaryString varchar(100),
                            ActualBinary AS CONVERT(varbinary(100), BinaryString));
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable (BinaryString)
VALUES(0x6806000004000000),
      (0x006806000004000000);
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.SomeTable;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.SomeTable;
```

Note that the values in the column `ActualBinary` *are* the binary values that are inserted. In your application though, you may get nothing. In ADS you get the value prefixed with a `h` for both rows, but in SSMS you get nothing for the row starting with a `null` character:

ADS:
[image]

SSMS:
[image]